# Shutdown Windows in Parallels stops other Parallels

Tags: parallels

I have Windows and Ubuntu instances of Parallels. When I have both running and I shutdown Ubuntu, Windows is unaffected. But when I have both running and I shutdown Windows, it shuts down Ubuntu as well. Has anyone else seen this and is there a way to prevent this?

I checked [here](http://kb.parallels.com/en/120414), and went to Virtual Machine -> Configure... -> Options -> Startup and Shutdown, and I set "On VM Shutdown" to "Keep window open" and "On Window Close" to "Ask me what to do". No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Under Virtual Machine -> Configure..., go to the General tab to make sure you're editing the configuration of the right VM.